# Can't access data in D3 within on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

The problem that I'm getting is that when I do console.log(d.info) within the on click event that I've set to be triggered whenever my svg element is clicked, I get an undefined error in the console.

Is there any way to access my data from my csv file that I've saved in the infoData variable?

Thanks in advance!

```
d3.csv("../data/dataset.csv", function(data) {
  var infoData = data;

  var svg = d3.select(".container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);

  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(infoData)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "#0000ff")
    .attr("width", function(d, index) {
      return (d.width);
    })
    .attr("height", 80);

  $(document).ready(function(d) {
    svg.on("click", function(event, d) {
      console.log(d.info);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the click handler to where you are defining your `rect`:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(buildingData)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "#0000ff")
    .attr("width", function(d, index) {
      return (d.width);
    })
    .attr("height", 80)
    .on('click', function(event, d) {
        console.log(d.info);
    })
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! still undefined though :(

Comment: Can you show your infoData? Or even better, create a plunker?